# password brute force over ssh? (not on ssh)

Tags: brute-force, hydra

Can  Hydra  ssh to remote host and attempt a password list against `su root`?

I am trying to recover the root password to an old device. It is an old Apple jailbroken Apple device, running IOS8.

The device is somewhat slow, but have no rate limit or delays. I am able to run 150 tries/min with hydra for the ssh password.

I can log in as one user, and I could try the passwords much faster (i.e. without SSH handshake every 3 tries) using `su root`. But it is not possible to run hydra there, i need hydra to login and then try the commands.

Is this possible with hydra? Should I use some other tool?

Comment: Pull the disk and change password? Or boot a live cd, and change the password?

Comment: it's a jailbroken apple device with IOS8. I can't do anything sane with it.

Comment: I've edited that into the question. Such information should be part of the question, as it's crucial to understanding the problem in the best way possible :)

Comment: Can you run commands via `sudo` as the user that you are able to login as?  If so, is it possible for you to `cat` the /etc/shadow file?

Comment: > "can you run commands via sudo". No. I mentioned `su root` just because that is the quickest way to try root's password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hydra does not support that mode.

The closest it comes is the Cisco Enable mode, where a telnet connection is used to log into the device and then the `enable` command is repeated to try different potential `enable` passwords.  It might be possible to write a new module by cribbing code from hydra-cisco-enable.c and hydra-ssh.c to do what you want.

Alternately, if you have `expect`, you can use that to write a [password guessing script](https://www.nicktailor.com/?p=287).

Answer (score -1):

Brute force is not a good solution unless you are sure password in your dictionary.

Worth to try:

If you have `sudo` permission, use it to root shell:

```
sudo su - root
```

If you are the host owner, just reboot to single user mode and change root password by `passwd`:

```
# passwd
```

see https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+boot+to+single+user+mode

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am trying brute force because I do not have sudo acess at all. While I do not have the password, I know myself to know I have certainly used a convenience password. that is, 3 to 6 chars, with only letters and numbers.